# Git: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to bitbucket.org:443

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssl, proxy, bitbucket

Using git 2.5.0 on an Ubuntu 15.10, I want to clone my repository from behind a corporate firewall:

`git clone https://<me>@bitbucket.org/etc/etc.git`

Proxy settings must be right because I frequently used them behind the same corporate proxy on the same hardware - using Ubuntu 14.10 then.

The process is interrupted with given error (see headline). Log trace is as follows:

```
* Cloning into '<MY-REPO>'...
* Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying     [...]
* Connected to [...]
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to bitbucket.org:443
> CONNECT bitbucket.org:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: bitbucket.org:443
User-Agent: git/2.5.0
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
< Proxy-Agent: IWSS
< Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 16:04:05 GMT
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to bitbucket.org:443 
* Closing connection 0
```

**FYI:** Before this error I had another one - [gnutls_handshake() failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers) which was resolved by compiling git with openssl instead of gnutls.

Thank You for any hint how to get around this error.

Comment: Hi Finnfalter, I was wondering did you get anywhere with this? I am getting very similar error. Thanks.